# Matching 2 columns in a table

Tags: mysql

Ok, here is my data.

```
Sault Ste. Marie, ON
Sault Ste. Marie, MI
Sault Ste. Marie, ON
Sault Ste. Marie, MI
```

I am trying to match and count the results.  Current results are 4 for Sault Ste. Marie, ON with the following code.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`city`) AS `countrink`
FROM markers
GROUP BY `city`
HAVING `countrink` >=2
ORDER BY `countrink` DESC
```

How can I match the 2 columns so the results read.
Sault Ste. Marie, ON 2
Sault Ste. Marie, MI 2

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked...

```
SELECT `city`, `prov`, COUNT(`city`) AS `countrink`
FROM markers
GROUP BY `city`, `prov`
HAVING `countrink` >=2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `city`, COUNT(`city`) AS `countrink`
FROM markers
GROUP BY `city`
HAVING `countrink` >= 2
ORDER BY `countrink` DESC
```

Although MySQL allows you to select columns outside of the `GROUP BY` clause, it produces *undefined* results. Therefore you can only reliably select `city` in addition to any aggregated columns.